# Flurry Ads iOS Banners dismiss

Tags: ios, objective-c, ads, banner, flurry

Does anybody have experience with Flurry Ads?  I am able to get their test ads to display.  However, when I display a banner ad, there is no 'x' for the user to dismiss the ad itself.  Does anyone know if this is intentional?  Do I have to write my own code to give the user a specific banner dismissal action?  Or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use Flurry Ads and no, there is no built-in close button on their banners. If you want the user to be able to close banners, you will need to create your own UI and implement the `removeAdFromSpace` method on your ad space.